# pandas create new column based on grouping

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like the following.

```
df =     index| date | amount| type|
           0  | 2015 | 1000  | A   |
           1  | 2015 | 100   | B   |
           2  | 2016 | 3500  | A   |
           3  | 2017 | 150   | C   |
```

I want to produce a dataframe with a new column based on types. The result would look like the following.

```
df =     index| date | A   | B   | C   
           0  | 2015 | 1000| 100 |0
           1  | 2016 | 3500| 0   |0
           2  | 2017 | 0   | 0   |150
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
ss=df.groupby(['date','type']).sum().reset_index()
ss.pivot(index='date',columns='type',values='amount').fillna(0)
```